# How to rewrite url with IIS7 Rewriter and question mark

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have an url like this :

mydomain/page?param1=1

and I want rewrite this to :

mydomain/page2?param1=1

```
<rule name="MyRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="page?(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="page2?{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

or

```
<rule name="MyRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="page\?(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="page2?{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This does not match,  I do not understand why

Answer (score 0):

The `?` marks the start of the query string, which is not part of the path.

So if I follow, the rewriter wont even get to see the `?` and anything past it.